# Multithreading with ADO.NET

Tags: c#, multithreading, ado.net, sqlconnection

I want to select some data from tables at the same time. When I am trying to do this with parallel threads an exception occurs. Should I use different `SqlConnection` objects for every `SqlCommand` or is there any technique to share same `SqlConnection` between several threads and execute several `SqlCommand` at the same time without exception.

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("...")
connection.Open();

List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    tasks.Add(Task.Run(() =>
    {
        var command = connection.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = "select top 1 * from Persons";
        var data = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (data.Read())
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{data[0]} {data[1]} {data[2]}");
        }
    }));
}

await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

connection.Close();
```

Comment: Arguably you are going to be limited mostly by the IO performance of the database, so multi-threading is pointless anyway. Side note: you *must* dispose your connection, command and reader objects with `using`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a separate connection for each concurrent operation. Since connections are pooled and reused, feel free to create a new one in the scope that you need it, and close it at the end (it is returned to the pool, not actually *closed*).

This is a limitation of the on-the-wire protocols for most (all?) database servers.